# Could not find devise mapping for path "/sessions/user" devise log in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, controller

Very frustrating for the last few days.

I have a rails app with Devise installed where I generated a new User model and I generated Devise views as well.

This happens when I try to sign in as an existing user right when I click "Log in" after filling out the email and password fields:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound - Could not find devise mapping for path "/sessions/user".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

:
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:84:in `unknown_action!'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:59:in `assert_is_devise_resource!'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:97:in `require_no_authentication'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:397:in `_run__1955514966561508052__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2142997860843545523__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

The thing is, when I sign up as a new user, it works just fine. I can fill in the appropriate fields, click "Sign up" and it notifies me that I've logged in successfully and redirects me to the root URL showing the user as logged in. The error only occurs when I try to log in.

Here are my routes:

```
Ripelist::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'signup' }
  root to: 'listings#index'
  match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post

  resources :users
  resources :listings
  resources :categories
  resources :sessions
end
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: this is wrong,  to: 'devise/sessions#create' ,

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in your routes.rb file, try wrapping your routes inside the scope block as the error message suggests.
Here is an example:

```
devise_scope :user do
   get "signup", to: "devise/registrations#new"
   get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
   get "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

This will give you nicely named routes.

And by the way, if you are using Rails 4, get rid of the match method. you need to specify the HTTP verb.

---

### OBSOLETE old answer:

(Below is the old obsolete version of the code, shown for reference. Use the code above.)

```
devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'signup' }
```

AND

```
match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what I should do to replace the match method. Could you elaborate? (I'm very new to rails!)

Comment: Wikea, the section labeled "update" is not the new code; it is the old code. He is showing that the `match` code and the `devise_for` code is old, and shouldn't be used. This is still confusing because usually sectioned labeled "Update" is the new stuff, not the old stuff.

Answer (score 44):

Be careful if you nave namespaced routes to declare the devise_scope a little different:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do 
  namespace :v1 do 
    devise_scope :api_v1_user do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This should be upvoted so people notice it. Very important for anyone doing namespaced API work!!

Answer (score 15):

This error (`AbstractController::ActionNotFound - Could not find devise mapping for path`) can arise if `devise_scope` is passed a plural scope instead of a singular scope.

The `devise_for` method takes a plural form of model scope (i.e. :users) whereas the `devise_scope` takes the singular form (i.e. `:user`).

From the devise documentations (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Adevise_scope):

> Also be aware of that 'devise_scope' and 'as' use the singular form of
>   the noun where other devise route commands expect the plural form.
>   This would be a good and working example.
>
> ```
> devise_scope :user do
>   get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
> end
> devise_for :users
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Error is telling you:

```
devise_scope :user do
  match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
end
```

did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

```
devise_scope :user do
  # add any route which is giving above error message
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/confirmation/phone/:token', to: 'users/confirmations#phone', as: :confirmation_phone
  end
```